# Want to get a Javascript stacktrace/callstack when unhandled exception occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-ui, error-handling

Sometimes I get an error or an unhandled exception in a line in the jQuery UI js file. I know the problem was an empty or null object or property was passed to jQuery. For example in Chrome I get a 'Uncaught TypeError" error.

Doing some manual work I can find the culprit and I can do better error handling. This could take some time.

However I am looking for a fast automatic way to find the culprit by looking at the stacktrace when the exception occurred.  Is there a modern browser which has this feature built in?

Or some JavaScript error handler which works across all the loaded js files in a global level?

I looked at [this article](http://eriwen.com/javascript/stacktrace-update/) but it seems I have to sprinkle printStackTrace() in all the targetted functions. I don't like this idea much if my code has many functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in webkit  (what chrome or safari uses) debug tools, click the Scripts section on the top.  then look for hexagon like icon on the bottom with the two vertical lines.  clicking that will cause javascript execution to pause on an error.  At the right you will see the callstack, where you can trace through everything.

Comment: I am appreciating Chrome Developer Tools more and more over FF's Firebug.

Comment: It seems to have disappeared in recent versions.